# JUnit: Enable assertions in class under test

Tags: java, junit, assertions

I've been bit a few times by Java `assert` statements that didn't fail in the JUnit test suite because assertions weren't enabled in JUnit's JVM instance. To be clear, these are "black box" assertions inside implementations (checking invariants, etc) not the assertions defined by the JUnit tests themselves. Of course, I'd like to catch any such assertion failures in the test suite.

The obvious solution is to be *really careful* to use `-enableassertions` whenever I run JUnit, but I'd prefer a more robust solution. One alternative is to add the following test to every test class:

```
  @Test(expected=AssertionError.class)
  public void testAssertionsEnabled() {
    assert(false);
  }
```

Is there a more automatic way to accomplish this? A system-wide configuration option to JUnit? A dynamic call I could put in the `setUp()` method?

Comment: Just a general question.  If you really want to thorough unit test your code, shouldn't you test with and without assertions enabled? One thing assertions are **really good** for is introducing unexpected side effects.

Comment: btw. how are you running the JUnit Testcases? If you have some build manager (ant, maven) it should be trivial to add this switch by default

Comment: @Alexander: That's not a bad idea.
@jitter: Of course you're right. Maven seems to enable assertions by default. I hadn't noticed before that Eclipse has a preference setting for this. The problem is these kinds of settings can change behind your back...

Comment: Did you consider my reworked answer? I proposed three possible solutions to your problem which all work (tested)

Answer (score 21):

In Eclipse you can go to `Windows` → `Preferences` → `Java` → `JUnit`, which has an option to add `-ea` everytime a new launch configuration is created. It adds the `-ea` option to the Debug Configuration as well.

The full text next to a check box is

> Add '-ea' to VM arguments when creating a new JUnit launch
>   configuration

Comment: do you have any kind of Unit test plugin in your Eclipse? I can't find that option.

Comment: No, it is part of the standard Eclipse installation

Comment: Which version of Eclipse do you use?

Comment: sorry, this was a long time ago. I don't have Eclipse installed on my PC anymore :(

Comment: I'm using Juno. It's in Window -> Preferences -> Java -> JUnit

Answer (score 5):

I propose three possible (simple?) fixes which work for me after a quick test (but you might need to check the side effects of using a static-initializer-block)

1.) Add a static-initializer block to those testcases which rely on assertions being enabled

```
import ....
public class TestXX....
...
    static {
        ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().setDefaultAssertionStatus(true);
    }
   ...
   @Test(expected=AssertionError.class)
   ...
...
```

2.) Create a base-class which all of your test-classes extend which need assertions enabled

```
public class AssertionBaseTest {
    static {
        //static block gets inherited too
        ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().setDefaultAssertionStatus(true);
    }
}
```

3.) Create a test suite which runs all your test

```
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.junit.runners.Suite;

@RunWith(Suite.class)
@Suite.SuiteClasses({
    //list of comma-separated classes
    /*Foo.class,
    Bar.class*/
})
public class AssertionTestSuite {
    static {
        //should run before the test classes are loaded
        ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().setDefaultAssertionStatus(true);
    }
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.main("AssertionTestSuite");
    }
}
```

Comment: That doesn't work in my case. It relies on the order that the classes get loaded.

Comment: Sorry, but this will not work as expected. Assertions must be enabled when loading and initializing a class and setting the default assertion status on the class loader will only affect classes, which are loaded later.

Answer (score 4):

Alternatively, you may compile your code such that assertions **cannot** be turned off. Under Java 6, you may use ["fa.jar – Force assertion check even when not enabled"](http://scg.unibe.ch/staff/adriankuhn/javacompiler/forceassertions), a small hack of mine.

Comment: Cool idea! It's not going to work for me, though, if it doesn't work in Eclipse.

Comment: this link is dead and I can't find a proper replacement. There is however a neat zero-dependency trick to force a class to only be usable with assertions turned on: http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=99

Answer (score 1):

As a friend of mine says... why take the time to write an assert if you are just going to turn it off?

Given that logic all assert statements should become:

```
if(!(....))
{
    // or some other appropriate RuntimeException subclass
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("........."); 
}
```

To answer your question a way you probably want :-)

```
import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.junit.runners.Suite;


@RunWith(Suite.class)
@Suite.SuiteClasses({
        FooTest.class,
        BarTest.class
        })
public class TestSuite
{
    @BeforeClass
    public static void oneTimeSetUp()
    {
        ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().setDefaultAssertionStatus(true);
    }
}
```

Then run the test suite rather than each test.  This should (works in my testing, but I did not read the internals of the JUnit framework code) result in the assertion status being set before any of the test classes are loaded.

Comment: Unless the assertion was shown to slow the code down to the point where it was a problem I would rather have them on all the time.  Preconditions/post conditions and any other type of assert statement - if you took the time to write it why turn it off?

Comment: If it's a precondition then my argument is that it isn't worthy of an assertion and should be checked and thrown as an IllegalArgumentException or whatever the appropriate exception is for that precondition. Postconditions are totally worthy of an assert though, assuming it's checking something more than @NotNull.

Comment: Assertions are still useful for private methods, where you want to check the preconditions during development but not in production.  Prefer exceptions on public interfaces unless there is a very good reason not to.